# Nvidia GeForce 930M driver and PCI bus error

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, pcie, lspci

I bought a new laptop ASUS-X556UF and installed Ubuntu 14.04 in it. Now I was trying to install Nvidia drivers according to the [tutorial](http://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/howto-install-latest-nvidia-driver-on-linux-without-getting-black-screen.7/).

At this point I noticed the problem with my system. When I switched to command line mode ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) there was continuous error display on my console. So I accessed my syslog to verify it. The same error was flushing my `/var/log/syslog` file. Below is the error I got:

```
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993338] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993342] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993351] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993700] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993723] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994075] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994078] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994080] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994090] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994439] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994464] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994816] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994818] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994820] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994829] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994837] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
```

So I tried to search with what device my PCI bus 'ic' was connected and thus I ran below command:

```
$ lspci -v -s 1c.0 | grep Bus:
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
$ lspci -s 1:0
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930M]
```

It was connected to my graphics card. I don't know what causing this problem. Is it because of driver or something else.

I also tried to install the proprietary driver in Ubuntu through additional drivers tab. But what I got is the black screen at login screen.

Please let me know what causing the error and also help to install nVidia driver and use it.

Thanks

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, you don't need to do any of that complicated setup. Just open the Additional Drivers app and select a proprietary video driver.

Comment: I did this ....and selected the proprietary driver 352 but when i rebooted my system after that..i got black screen

Comment: See if any of this helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Nope tried this ...black screen only comes when i install proprietary nvidia driver through additional driver app.

Comment: You may want to try installing Ubuntu 15.10 instead. The 930M is a pretty new card.

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same problem on Asus R556U. The problem was solved by booting with `pci=nomsi` (found the solution [on this page](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1509.0/01331.html))

In order to boot with `pci=nomsi`:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

once the file is opened in gedit replace

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
```

Save and close gedit window.
Update grub and restart your system:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: By adding `pcie_aspm=off` also works for me. Source: comment in bug #1521173 [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173/comments/32]

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 16.04. Asus x455lf i3-4005u

I've got the same card, after days of fighting to install its binary drivers, I've found out that the drivers on the Ubuntu's repos were old for my card.

I've added ppa:graphics-drivers and installed nvidia-367 (367-44 for the record).

Now It works nice without any noticeable issues. Only minor corruption of unity panel after lock/switching account that I can sole with pressing meta key.

kernel:4.4.0-38-generic
Un-modified /etc/default/grub