# Log files filling up hardrive + can't shut down computer

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, shutdown, log

I've just finished doing a dual boot installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on my new computer. It's an ASUS VivoBook X541UV-BH71-CB. I had some problems durng the installation but most of them were solved by doing the update and driver installation. However some issues are still bothering me.

1. My hard drive gets filled in an hour by log files

   ```
   oumar@oumar-ubuntu:/var/log$ ls -lhS
   total 203G
   rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  102G déc 30 13:00 kern.log
   rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   86G déc 30 06:58 syslog.1
   rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   16G déc 30 13:00 syslog
   rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  154M déc 29 06:13 syslog.2.gz
   rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  57K jui 19 16:42 bootstrap.log
   rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  47K déc 29 17:47 alternatives.log
   rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  46K déc 29 22:56 dpkg.log
   ```

I have a 250G partition for Ubuntu.
Here are the last lines of the problematic files

kern.log:

```
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478653] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478654] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478665] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478667] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478668] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478673] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478680] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478683] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478695] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478696] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478708] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478710] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478711] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478720] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478729] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478731] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478743] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478745] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 12:55:39 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [ 4008.478756] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
```

syslog.1 :

```
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019372] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019379] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019381] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019382] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019406] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019413] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019415] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019417] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019439] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019446] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019451] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019456] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019471] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019480] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019487] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019490] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019504] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019510] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019512] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec 30 06:58:41 oumar-ubuntu kernel: [  591.019514] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
```

I guess this problem is just the consequence of something else, which brings me to my second problem.

2. Can't shut down the computer

Every time I try to shutdown the computer normally, it just goes on a black screen and I have to shut it down by pressing the button.

3. Computer running slow

My computer is running surprisingly slow on Ubuntu despite the good hardware. I'm bit worried about this because the main reason why I installed Ubuntu is to do some programming work.

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/748078/nvidia-geforce-930m-driver-and-pci-bus-error) looks to be related.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the answer to my question here : [Nvidia GeForce 930M driver and PCI bus error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748078/nvidia-geforce-930m-driver-and-pci-bus-error)

The solution is to boot with pci=nomsi.
I don't know why this worked, but it did!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit /etc/syslog.conf (or rsyslog.conf, depending on what syslog program you have installed) and control what actually gets logged or not for some of those files. That will help slow down the log file fill up so you can troubleshoot those PCIe bus errors.

One other thing, that may or may not help... You can move the log file aside, and create a symlink that points to another partition with more space. Then then log will follow the symlink and log to the other partition. Odd work around, I know, but it could save you some time and headache troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Without beating around bushes, it would be far more straight forward doing a full system reinstall. I have a similar model [X541S] that had similar problems. These Asus machines need regular-ish BIOS updates as I've learned. i would advise going to you're local regions Asus website to download the MB sized flash image for free, i solved my problem in an hour, along with a fresh Linux installation, just download you're correct models firmware to a formatted usb stick then enter BIOS settings, select easy-flash then follow instruction from there... no sweat