# Ubuntu 16.04 running out of disk space

Tags: 16.04, disk, disk-usage, log

recently I installed ubuntu 16.04 on my HP ProBook 440 G3 on a 30 GB partition. But after using some days the whole disk just filled up. I have used 16.04 on just 10 GB space on a different PC without any problem. I have added the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRKe1.png) of root directory. please let me know how to fix this problem.

[image]

UPDATE:

I checked the syslog and found a file is constantly updating , added the screen shot.  I don't understand what is the problem here. Also these are the lines I see when I boot up. Also added the `lspci` output

[image: screenshot]

```
koushik@Koushik-HP:/var/log$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

UPDATE:

I have tried adding the boot parameter  `pci=nomsi`, `pci=noaer` and `pcie_aspm=off` but no luck.

Comment: It looks like you have a large amount of log files. Log files are created if there are any errors, or other events that you may want to look at. Lokk at [Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866243/log-files-filling-up-hardrive-cant-shut-down-computer)

Comment: You seem to have a problem with logging, try the **System Log App**

Comment: You should unfold the log tree to investigate which log is producing the large amount of data. 
Also keep in mind some of the log dfirectories require super user access to be investigated.

Comment: But how can I know and fix what is the error? @ThompsonDawes what is System Log App

Comment: Upper left corner, top of the Launcher bar, click on 'search your computer' and enter: 'System Log,' You should see the icon a white page with a gray loupe (magnifying glass) on it. With that Ubuntu App you can read and control system log files. If you study your logs you may determine what is wrong with your system.

Comment: You have a hardware error or driver error. From the supplied information I can't see what it is.