# systemd-journald high CPU usage

Tags: cpu, systemd-journald

A few days ago, I installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my Asus laptop dual-boot with Windows 10 and shortly thereafter, I noticed that the `systemd-journald` process was constantly using 25-35% of CPU.

I traced the process and saved part of the output is at [here.](https://pastebin.com/9RW1Dk9f)

It seems that the CPU is looping, doing something that is related to a pci device.

Does anyone have any advice on the problem?

Answer (score 7):

@S_n Can you please check the logs, and see whether it gives an indication about the problem?

I've had the same problem and that caused an infinite loop, and the CPU was constantly higher than 30%.

So if you run in the terminal `journalctl` you can check it the log in the terminal.

I fixed it by adding a `pci=nomsi` parameter to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT property(you can find and edit it in: `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`)

After adding the parameter update the grub: `sudo update-grub` and then reboot.
Then run `top` in the terminal, and see whether that fixed it.

> Note: By doing that you'll add the parameter permanently, however you can  do it temporarily

If you want to add it temporarily, as following:

1. Start your system and wait for the GRUB menu to show (if you don't see a GRUB menu, press and hold the left `Shift` key after starting the system).
2. Now highlight the kernel you want to use, and press the <kbd>e</kbd> key. You should be able to see and edit the commands associated with the highlighted kernel.
3. Go down to the line starting with `linux` and add your parameter `pci=nomsi` to its end.
4. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

Comment: What problem did you have with `linux_default_parameter` and how did you fix it? You can't just say you have a problem and not say what the fix is.

Comment: As it stands, this doesn't really seem to answer the question.

Comment: My bad, sorry for not doing that.

The problem was that a parameter in the grub configuration file was missing, and that caused to an infinite loop, and the cpu was constantly higher then 30%.
Therefore I asked can you check what does it say in the terminal, so if you run in the terminal ` journalctl` you'll get a log, and the problem that I faced was described there, and fixed it by adding a `pci=nomsi` parameter to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` property, and then update the grub: `sudo update-grub` and the reboot.

I hope that it's more clear now!

Comment: @HasanSh You should add that to your answer since some people may not read comments.

Comment: @edwinksl Sure:)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/748078/nvidia-geforce-930m-driver-and-pci-bus-error is helpfull too

Answer (score 1):

ADD  pcie_aspm=off parameter to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX property
by running 
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
after

$ sudo update-grub 
$ reboot

Answer (score 0):

This workaround solved the problem in my computer (Ubuntu 17.10 x64): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1723362/comments/11

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/gnome-software
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

The problem is caused by `snapd-glib`, that logs hundreds / thousands of lines per minute in the `/var/log/syslog` like these:

```
Jan 29 11:12:28 hostXXX gnome-software[1723]: Ignoring unexpected response
Jan 29 11:12:28 hostXXX gnome-software[1723]: g_byte_array_remove_range: assertion 'index_ + length <= array->len' failed
```

My `/var/log/syslog` got 9.5 Gb of size before update the module and purge the content.