# systemd-journald crashed with SIGABRT in pthread_sigmask()

Tags: 18.04, suspend, lenovo, systemd, systemd-journald

Fresh install of Ubuntu `18.04` on a new Lenovo x1c6, I'm getting this error sometimes after resuming from suspend.

I have no idea what it means, and search online leads to a [bug report that doesn't exist](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1754214)

Might be related: my battery life is 4-5 hours, and this Lenovo is reported by other Ubuntu users to have 10+ hours. [See related thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906251/systemd-journald-high-cpu-usage)

The answer in that thread suggests running the following:

```
➜  ~ journalctl
-- Logs begin at Fri 2018-05-18 13:10:19 CEST, end at Tue 2018-05-22 19:25:25 CEST. --
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: Linux version 4.15.0-20-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-039) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubu
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=2da2702a-fc2a
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  832, xstate_sizes[3]:   64
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]:  896, xstate_sizes[4]:   64
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, context size is 960 bytes, using 'compact
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000057fff] usable
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000058000-0x0000000000058fff] reserved
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000059000-0x000000000009cfff] usable
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000044f7dfff] usable
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044f7e000-0x0000000044f7efff] ACPI NVS
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044f7f000-0x0000000044f7ffff] reserved
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000044f80000-0x000000004e8d9fff] usable
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000004e8da000-0x000000004ff1afff] reserved
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000004ff1b000-0x000000004ff99fff] ACPI NVS
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000004ff9a000-0x000000004fffefff] ACPI data
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000004ffff000-0x000000004fffffff] usable
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000050000000-0x0000000057ffffff] reserved
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000058600000-0x000000005c7fffff] reserved
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe010000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
May 18 13:10:19 goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000004a27fffff] usable
```

His problem was caused by fixed his high CPU problem by doing this:

> I fixed it by adding a `pci=nomsi` parameter to the
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` property(you can find and edit it in:  `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`)
>
> After adding the parameter update the grub: `sudo update-grub` and then
>   reboot. Then run top in the terminal, and see whether that fixed it.

I don't want to mess with `grub` without further advice. Too many bricked computers running around these days :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Here is an updated bug report firstly closed as duplicate and then reopened:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1777739 But since it has no activity, it is almost useless.

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: A good reference for MSI is https://github.com/diaevd/ubuntu-xenial/blob/master/Documentation/PCI/MSI-HOWTO.txt .`sudo lspci -vv | grep -i msi` will show where MSI is enabled (`Enable+`)  or disabled (`Enable-`), cf Section 4.6, ibid. Disabling MSI shouldn't break anything, you can try it once by editing the grub command manually at boot (see eg any grub user docs) to add the `pci=nomsi` flag. In my system MSI is only disabled for devices where MSI-X is enabled.

Comment: @tatsu why do you think I've found a solution?

Comment: nevermind. since you used the past tense I thought it was solved.

Answer (score 1):

i have a weak memory that in the systemd area there have been problems for some installations that might have expressed in a similar sort of log.
the solution for that was just updating systemd to a more current version that had a fix included that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

For odd, hard-to-trace issues concerning power management, including suspend/resume and hibernate/wake, my 1st recommended step is always simply this: check that your system firmware is current, and if it's not, update it.

This resolves a lot of such problems, in my experience.