# serious problem at logout time

Tags: xorg, shutdown, logout

I have a serious problem at logout or shutdown time, Actually when I want to log out of session or shutdown the laptop and I press the shutdown button the screen gets to CLI and shown some text about Xorg and the laptop won't be turn off so I have to turn it off with the power button.

Here is a photo of what I receive:

[image]

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211 suggests it may be a problem with your PSU.

Comment: What make/model laptop? Did this problem just start, or has it always happened this way? Do you know how to temporarily add `nomodeset` to your GRUB boot parameters?

Comment: Laptop model: Asus PRO P2540UV-A, and actually this problem always happen when device has a long uptime e.g. last night my uptime was in 10h and did not shutdown so I had to press the power button to turn it off. And no, I don't know how to add >nomodeset to GRUB. I didn't have this problem in Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/748078/nvidia-geforce-930m-driver-and-pci-bus-error and https://askubuntu.com/questions/863150/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-type-physical-layer-id-00e5receiver-id/863301. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.